# I cannot lock Cordova screen mode using screen orientation plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I can't lock my screen mode to portrait using the screen orientation plugin in Cordova android
Every time I tried it allowed me to rotate to landscape mode

I tried to use this code but it doesnt work

```
            function onDeviceReady() {
                screen.orientation.lock('portrait-primary')
            }

            document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
                onDeviceReady()
            })
```

I expect it to lock the mode to portrait mode but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reason why you are using a plugin for this? You can simply set

```
 <preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In our app we do it like this:

```
  window.screen.orientation.lock('portrait-primary');
```

So I think your problem is that you are not calling it on the window. screen is a property in window, you cannot call on it directly, I think.